# multiple virtual machines for different 'main' OS configurations

Tags: windows-7, vmware

First of all this post might be filled with some opinionated assertions and also error prone in some manner, but as a relative newbie in this matter I assume the risk.

#### The problem as I see it

As a user of Windows operating systems and services for the past many years I encountered many situations when after running the OS for months/years, installing and using software, games, moving files around etc. the OS gets kind of bloated and starts having performance issues. Besides the 'classic' time and energy consuming solution of reinstalling the OS another option would be uninstalling not needed products, run disk cleanup and defragmentation. However, even after those steps the OS would not be as fast and clean as it would be after a fresh install. Another related issue would be the fact that if all software (big .NET stuff, various mobile SDKs, various software, games, editing tools, Adobe stuff etc.) is installed in the same OS 'container', then I believe running any of the installed components will be less efficient because of the overall processes of all the installed other components running, some of which is better not to forcefully close from the task manager or etc.

#### Proposed solution

Regarding this I was thinking of setting up a very basic Windows/Linux installment that can support VMWare and have multiple dedicated machines available to which you would give maximum resources when running them: for example a .NET development machine, or a dedicated mobile (Android for example) development machine, dedicated gaming machine, etc. The advantages I see going this way would be: portability of the whole OSs, the fact that you can easily take snapshots and if an 'environment' gets bloated you can easily revert to a previous stable state and also the fact that (as mentioned) you would have almost clean windows installments on each virtual machine. A disadvantage would be shared components that basically have to live on each machine.

The questions would be: is this option feasible/efficient? Does it make sense to try something like this? If going this way on top of a Windows system how would VM use affect physical disk fragmentation?

Comment: I see what your saying, but no. It wouldn't be efficient. Personally, I use a lot of software, for various tasks, that I've accumulated over the years and there isn't a noticeable lack in performance when I do this (across dozens of machines). Perhaps you should focus on maintenance of the system? Also, `de/frag` honestly has very little impact or importance when it comes to recent HDD's. It's been entirely eliminated with SSD's. Virtual Machines can be really convenient as far as portability, having a custom configured OS ready to go, I would just never use them for reasons you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Will it be efficient? No, of course not.  You'll be chewing up lots of GB of space just for the various base OS installs.

Is it feasible?  Certainly.  Is it a good idea?  That's an opinionated question, and you will get various responses to it.

I CAN tell you that I do this exactly, in two forms.

In the first form, a less-specialized form, I have an ubuntu VM that I use for audio editing (I use Ardour).  I've installed ardour, openSSH server, and nothing else.  I even removed some of the default programs that come pre-packaged (like open/libreoffice).  Then, when I have some audio editing to do, I create a second virtual disk, and put all of the data associated with that session on there.  When I have a different project to work on, I boot the VM with a different data disk.  It's a single clean OS, with multiple data drives.

The second form is more along the lines of what you're saying.  I run Windows Server 2012 R2 on my machine, and then have three Hyper-V VMs running on top of it.  Two of them are dedicated dev servers for two separate projects I'm involved with (both running apache and mysql), and the third is a private TOR entry node.  (This is more or less how servers frequently run in the corporate world...a bunch of VMs inside some sort of host).

What YOU seem to be suggesting is running the CLIENT machine inside a vm, and for that you are going to have some additional considerations.  The thing that grabbed my eye the most in your post is that you wanted a dedicated gaming machine.  I still have not come across any virtualization software that is super fantastic at 3D gfx, so watch out for that.  True, I can play Starcraft 2 at a halfway decent framerate on my windows client on my mac using Parallels....but it's not great.

In any virtualization environment, there's going to be some slowdown, due to the virtualization layer.  The upside is that you get to do more things.

TLDR: I'd recommend you have your actual physical machine as the gaming rig, and then put some VMs on there for development and whatnot.

Comment: Thanks for the gaming related info, somehow I hadn't thought about it. Regarding audio editing, that's a thing I have to do from time to time, however I would need a Windows VM as there are no drivers for my audio card that work decently on Linux machines. Anyway, the whole point of this should be if a VM with full given resources from the main OS and minimum software installed works better than a normal OS with all the programs/features installed. I think I'll give it a try after getting enough spare time to prepare the transition.